# No module named 'requests_aws4auth' when trying to import in a lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.6

I need my lambda to call an API Gateway and have the following code in place as inline code for the lambda in my cloud formation template.

```
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
def handler(event,context):
          client = boto3.client('sts')
          responseAssumeRole = client.assume_role(
            DurationSeconds=3600,
            RoleArn='arn',// real arn of the api gateway invocation role
            RoleSessionName='Bob',
          )
          credentials = responseAssumeRole['Credentials']
          auth = AWS4Auth(aws_access_key=responseAssumeRole['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                                 aws_secret_access_key=responseAssumeRole['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
                                 aws_host='host.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
                                 aws_region='us-east-1',
                                 aws_service='execute-api')
          headers= {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
          response = requests.get('https://host.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test',
                                  auth=auth, headers=headers)
```

This gives me the following error

```
No module named 'requests_aws4auth'
```

Any solution or alternative way to get the auth created using the aws credentials would be also welcome.

Comment: Amazon Web Services version 4 authentication Library `pip install requests-aws4auth`

Comment: @RoshanBagdiya how do you do a pip install inside a lambda before importing it??

Comment: you can't really do it before with the pip approach. try making a Lambda layer or packaging everything into a zip (which is then uploaded and referenced from s3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package your source code and dependencies in a zip file, upload it to S3, and then use the S3Bucket and S3Keys Properties under your AWS::Lambda::Function resource.

e.g. On Linux:

```bash
mkdir project-dir
cp myhandler.py project-dir
pip install module-name -t /path/to/project-dir

# zip the contents of project-dir , this is your deployment package
cd project-dir
zip -r deployme.zip .
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the accepted answer works, I want to post this resource as well. If you do not want to package it and upload to S3 and still searching for an alternative approach to have the same functionality in an inline lambda, this will help. If you use this approach you do not need to use 'requests_aws4auth' in the first place.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

You can replace the following

```
access_key = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
secret_key = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
```

with the values you got from the assume role request like this

```
access_key=responseAssumeRole['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
secret_key=responseAssumeRole['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
```

Comment: Underappreciated, simple answer. Worked for me, upped. For python, this means reusing boto3 (already there in AWS Lambda). See https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1784#issuecomment-659132830 for signing request snippet. I ended up adapting STS assume role response to boto3 like this: 
```
from botocore.credentials import ReadOnlyCredentials
c=assumed_role_object['Credentials']
boto_creds = ReadOnlyCredentials(secret_key = c['SecretAccessKey'], access_key = c['AccessKeyId'], token = c["SessionToken"])
```